# For a monotonic function on $(a,b)$ it holds that $w_f (x) =|f(x+)-f(x-)|$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

For a monotonic function on $(a,b)$ it holds that $w_f (x) =|f(x+)-f(x-)|$

This is an exercise from Heuser Analysis 1 (page 242) that I want to solve :

I know that 
$$f\in B[a,b] \text{ is continuous in} \ x\in [a,b] \Leftrightarrow w_f (x) = 0 $$

where $B[a,b]$ is the space of bounded functions on the interval of $a$ to $b$  $$w_{f}(x):= \lim _{\delta \rightarrow 0+} \Omega_{f}(U_{d}(x)\cap [a,b])$$ and $$\Omega_{f}(T):= \sup f(T)-\inf(T) = \sup\{ |f(x)-f(y)|:x,y\in T\}$$

But that doesn't seem to help here, because the function is not bounded. How does one show that for a monotonous function on $(a,b)$ it holds that $w_f (x) =|f(x+)-f(x-)|$
 ? ($f(x+)$ and $f(x-)$ are the left and right side limits, but it isn't even clear that they exist?

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know the definition of $w_f$.

Comment: But of course the function *is* bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For an interval $T=[c,d]$, if $f$ is monotonic then

$$\Omega_{f}(T)=|f(d)-f(c)|$$

**Second Hint:** For $\delta$ small enough you have $U_{\delta}(x)\cap [a,b]=(x-\delta, x+\delta)$. Use now that

$$[x-\delta/2, x+\delta/2] \subset (x-\delta, x+\delta) \subset [x-\delta, x+\delta]$$ and

$$\Omega_{f}([x-\delta/2, x+\delta/2])=|f(x+\delta/2)-f(x-\delta/2)|$$
$$\Omega_{f}([x-\delta, x+\delta])=|f(x+\delta)-f(x-\delta)|$$

Comment: I don't see where to go with this, you get : $w_f = \lim _{d\rightarrow 0+} |f(c)-f(d)|$ for $w_f$, how to continue?

Comment: @bakabakabaka I added a second hint, how the proof should be straightforward...

Comment: I see, now only taking the limit is left and it follows. Thank you.